# How to access to Slim container from other classess?

Tags: slim

Suppose that in my `dependencies.php` file I setup this container:

```
<?php

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['db'] = function($config)
{
  $db = $config['settings']['db'];
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db['host'] . ";port=" . $db['port'] .
  ";dbname=" . $db['dbname'] . ";charset=" . $db['charset'], $db['user'], $db['pass']);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $pdo;
};
```

I can use this `container` inside my `route`, called for example `table.php`:

```
<?php

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

$app->get('/table/get_table', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
  $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM some_table");
  $sql->execute();
  $result = $sql->fetchAll();
  return $response->withJson($result);
});
```

this is basically the default usage, right? Said that, how can I instead use the `db` container from other classes? Supposes I have created a class called `TableUtility` and imported inside the `table.php`:

```
class TableUtility
{
    function GetTableFromDb()
    {
       $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM some_table");
       $sql->execute();
       $result = $sql->fetchAll();
       return $response->withJson($result);
    }
}
```

as you can see I moved the logic of `PDO` inside `GetTableFromDb` of `TableUtility`, how can I access to `db` container from this class?
The usage in `table.php` will be:

```
<?php

use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

$app->get('/table/get_table', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
  $tableUtility = new TableUtility();
  return $response->withJson($tableUtility->GetTableFromDb());
});
```

actually I get in `TableUtility`:

> Call to a member function prepare() on null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full name for what you refer to as `container` is `Dependency Injection Container`. It is supposed to contain dependencies for objects. Passing this container to objects is considered bad practice. Instead you should pass only required dependencies for that object, which in your case is to pass `db` to `$tableUtility`. This is usually used by passing dependencies when constructing the object, or using setter methods. In your case you can refactor your code like this:

```
class TableUtility
{
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Now in any method of `TableUtility` class, you have access to db object using `$this->db` but you'll need to pass db to class constructor whenever you create a new object. So you also need to do this:

```
$app->get('/table/get_table', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
  $tableUtility = new TableUtility($this->db);
  // rest of the code
});
```